# Question if a class in Python like this is correct

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a beginner. I have a question if this code snippet is acceptable in creating a Class in Python. It is a class of a ball for a pong game in python.
It works but is it good programming practice what I am doing. As you can see I am using pygame and using it directly in the draw method. Particularly this part I wonder if this is ok.

```
class Ball(pygame.rect.Rect):
   def __init__(self,left,top,width,height):
      super() .__init__(left,top,width,height)
      self.color = (255,0,0)


   def draw(self,screen):

       pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,self)
```

Comment: No it is not, because the indentation is incorrect.

Comment: Do not derive from `pygame.rect.Rect`. The "PyGame" way is to use a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object

Comment: Yes I see thanx @Rabbid76 the methods are not indented here it is in my program but apart from that ? And if I chose to derive from pygame.rect.Rect anyway is it in essence correct?

Answer (score 0):

Do not derive from [`pygame.rect.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). The "PyGame" way is to use a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) object